# SQL, Postgresql: shorthand for multiple OR conditions containing position()

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a better way to write this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
 POSITION('x' in field1) > 0 OR
 POSITION('x' in field2) > 0 OR
 POSITION('x' in field3) > 0 OR
 etc...
 ;
```

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
 POSITION('x' in (field1, field2, field3, etc...)) > 0
```

Comment: I would use `like` rather than `position()` because I think the former is more "SQLish".  However, I don't think there is a shorthand for what you want to do.  I will caution that this sort of problem sometimes means that you want to store values that are in columns in separate rows.

Comment: I agree the like is more SQLish, it's also may be overkill for this use case since it supports a much wider range of searches than position (though less than the a full regex would). It'd be interesting to see performance of each.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a native way to do this, but you could wrap it in a function pretty easily.  Based on your comment that you may want to apply this to other functions, it would be scalable in that you can keep the boilerplate -- the loop within the function -- in place and change the evalution logic to meet your future needs.

It also applies short-circuting, in that when it finds a positive value, it will exit without evaluating everything else unnecessarily.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION any_position(search_text text, variadic text_values text[])
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
  declare
    element text;
    pos integer;
  begin
    foreach element in array text_values
    loop
      pos := position (search_text in element);
      if pos > 0 then
        return pos;
      end if;
    end loop;

    return 0;
  end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Example invocation:

```
select any_position ('x', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven')
```

Comment: This could work. I'm not super experienced with composing SQL functions - could your suggestion be modified to take a table_name + column_names as arguments (instead of text_values)? ie, so it can be used to search any given set of columns for search_text?

Comment: While that's definitely possible, it would mean you would be creating dynamic DML within your function.  I tend to shy away from that, just because it seems like it opens up security holes.  Is there a specific use case you have in mind?  If you can elaborate on that, maybe there is a better solution that does not involve dynamic DML.  If you do, I'd recommend posting it as a new question -- I'd be happy to take a look (although others will likely beat me to the punch)

Answer (score 0):

You can always concatenate the strings and use them as one argument:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
 POSITION('x' in (field1 || field2 || field3) ) > 0
```

Note that that concatenation with || will give you NULL if any of field1, field2, field3 are null, while concatenation with the concat function will not:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
 POSITION('x' in concat(field1, field2, field3) ) > 0
```

If you're searching for one character, that should be fine. However if you're searching for, e.g. "ax" and you don't want to match if field1 ends in 'a' and field2 starts with 'x', then you can also include a separator between the arguments with the concat_ws function, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
 POSITION('x' in concat_ws('_##_', field1, field2, field3) ) > 0
```

Comment: Does this add notable overhead to concatenate all the fields prior to searching for 'x'? In my original example, I presume if the first clause is true ('x' is in field1), then field2 and field3 would not even be evaluated, saving resources.

Comment: It's true that this approaches requires concatenation, but the postgres WHERE evaluation order is non-deterministic in the sense that there's no guarantee that it will evaluate the field1 condition and not the others if that resolves to true. You might also see this behavior if you try to build in, say, zero value checks. E.g. you may still get a divide by zero error if you include "x<>0 OR 1/x>3" (though you can force evaluation order using a CASE statement). I'd suggest doing an EXPLAIN ANALYZE on your actual db to see if there's a worthwhile difference.